# Machines always trying to use encryption when connecting to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, encryption, sqlconnection

Since last week I have some machines that always try and encrypt a connection to SQL server.  This will cause some clients to fail, because all the SQL Servers are suing the default 'fallback' certificate, we don't have a CA certificate, so Invoke-SqlCmd for example will return an error saying the "The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not
trusted" (unless I add the -TrustServerCertificate switch).  This is a problem as we have many different connections and some providers dont allow you to specify to trust server cert of not to encrypt.

The machines it is happening on cannot connect to any SQL Server for this reason, and we have other machines that can connect to all SQL servers, so this suggests its a client problem, not a problem with the SQL Servers.

I can see in the Wireshark trace that the value for ‘tds.prelogin.option.encryption’ is set to 0 for the working client and 1 for the non working client, so something has caused these clients to always ask for encryption.

I have not found any patches applied at the time this started happening, and am not aware of any security policy changes either (although I would be interested to know what configuration might cause this so I can verify)

Comment: Have a big software update recently? Since around Feb 2022 most of Microsoft's SQL Server drivers had a breaking change with the Encryption default changing from false/no to true/yes. e.g.: [JDBC Driver 10.2](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/jdbc-driver-10-2-for-sql-server-released/ba-p/3100754); [ODBC Driver 18](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/odbc-driver-18-0-for-sql-server-released/ba-p/3169228); [OLE DB Driver 19.0](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/ole-db-driver-19-0-for-sql-server-released/ba-p/3170362).

Comment: That's interesting.  There certainly seems a move to "Default Encrypt".  But no, no updates identified on those machine, and I see ODBC and OLE DB, but I am testing with Invoke-SqlCmd and I believe that would ADO.NET, and I cant find a similar article for that.

Comment: [Released: General Availability of Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 4.0](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/released-general-availability-of-microsoft-data-sqlclient-4-0/ba-p/2983346) from Nov 2021, or [Released: General Availability of Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 5.0](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/released-general-availability-of-microsoft-data-sqlclient-5-0/ba-p/3592710) from Aug 2022?

Comment: Have you updated the `SqlServer` PowerShell module to 22.0.59 on the affected machines? As mentioned in its [package details/release notes](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/SqlServer/22.0.59) they switched its backend over to Microsoft.Data.SqlClient which does encrypt-by-default as mentioned in the above release links.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning yes, and that is the common thing on all the machines I tested on (using Invoke-SqlCmd) .  The reason I was testing was I was having problems with on premise Azure Data Gateway, so this explains why invoke-sqlcmd is failing.  Now I need to figure out why GW is failing,